# No matching ExtType found

Tags: c#, php, .net, web-services, soap

I am connecting via PHP and SOAP to a Microsoft .NET Webservice. I was told that this is a "webservice" so I am under the impression that it should behave like the 954 other "webservices" that I have worked with in the past.

Calls that don't involve parameters seem to work fine. Ex,

```
$client->GetContactsDataTableXMLSchema();
```

And the result is what you probably would expect, an XML schema of a contact Table. No problems there.

HOWEVER,

Any time I try to make a call that involves a parameter all heck breaks loose and all I ever get is the error:

```
No matching ExtType found
```

Is this a standard MS .NET error? Is this something I am doing wrong in PHP Soap? I can't really share the soap end point because it is private/confidential along with the WSDL.

Here is the function I am calling:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <FetchDIASContact xmlns="http://www.cac.be/">
      <applicationName>string</applicationName>
      <workspace>string</workspace>
      <addressTable>string</addressTable>
      <addressID>string</addressID>
    </FetchDIASContact>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is how I am calling it.

```
$client->FetchDIASContact( 'MyVastiauWebApplication' , '100' , 'Client' , '987654321' );
```

The first 3 params were given to me be the webservice maker and defined in in C# example they made. The last parameter is the client we want to fetch which in the Visual Studio C# example app they gave works.

Lastly,

Will I have any chance at all when the result does come back of actually reading and decoding the data in the results?

I have a bad feeling that the results are going to be a MS .NET dataTable that has to be decoded from a byte stream.

Here is the result I am going to be getting when it does work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <FetchDIASContactResponse xmlns="http://www.cac.be/">
      <FetchDIASContactResult>string</FetchDIASContactResult>
      <addressesDT>base64Binary</addressesDT>
      <fieldsDT>base64Binary</fieldsDT>
      <linksDT>base64Binary</linksDT>
    </FetchDIASContactResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK,

After banging my head and running into walls here is what I found, I share it with you so if you have the same problem you know what to do.

Some webservices require that when you call a function you wrap the parameters up into an associative array.

Many webservices just let you put the parameters in the call normally. This is working and the parameters are key value array.

```
$client->FetchDiasContactV5( array(
    'applicationName' => 'MyVastiauWebApplication' ,
    'workspace' => '100' ,
    'addressTable' => 'Client' ,
    'addressID' => '987654321' ) );
```

Calling the function like this:

```
$client->FetchDIASContact( 'MyVastiauWebApplication' , '100' , 'Client' , '987654321' );
```

Did not work, however I am certain that in other webservices that I have connected to it did... No biggie we move along.